# How to re-render vue js using emit event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a global.js and I'm emitting an event to global.js What I want to achieve is whenever the value of my global.js re-render the vue.

**global.js**

```
 export let globalStore = new Vue({
   data: {
   translateBool: 0,
   about: [`About Us`,`フィリピンのマニラに 2015年9月に設立。`]
  },
  methods: {
    changeLanguage(){
        if(this.translateBool == 0){
            this.translateBool= 1
        }else{
            this.translateBool= 0
        }
    }
  }
})

    globalStore.$on('changeLanguage',globalStore.changeLanguage)
```

**click.vue**

```
import { globalStore } from '../../global.js';

    export default{
        name: "sample",
        data(){
            return{
            language: globalStore.translate
        }
        },
        methods : {
            changeLanguage(){
            globalStore.$emit('changeLanguage')
            },
          }
        }
    }
</script>   

{{language}}
```

Even though `translateBool` is = 1, the output doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data properties set in the `data` method are only set once during the Vue instance's initialization.

If you want the `language` property to update based on the current state of the `globalStore.language` value, you should make it a computed property:

```
export default {
  name: "sample",
  computed: {
    language() { 
      return globalStore.translate
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLanguage() {
      globalStore.$emit('changeLanguage')
    }
  }
}
```